# Print dice image using asterisk

Tags: c#

I doing a school activity and we need to get 2 random numbers and display them with a dice image using an asterisk. The problem is that it does not display the output that I expect.

Here's the code:

```
            int i, j;

            Console.Write("PRESS ENTER TO GENERATE RANDOM NUMBER.......\n\n");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Random ramnum = new Random();
            int dice = ramnum.Next(1, 7); //First random number 
            int die = ramnum.Next(1, 7);  //second random number
            Console.WriteLine("Dice 1: \t" + dice);
            Console.WriteLine("Dice 2: \t" + die);
            Console.WriteLine(" ");//separate the number and asterisk

            //first number asterisk
            
                for (i = 1; i <= dice; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("*"); //print asterisk for first number

            }
            Console.Write(" ");//space between to two asterisk

            //second number asterisk
            for (j = 1; j <= die; j++)
            { 
                    Console.Write("*"); //prints at border place
                }
             

        }
    }
}
```

The result:

```
Dice 1:         1
Dice 2:         3

 * ***
```

The desire output:

```
Dice 1:         5
Dice 2:         6

 *** ***
 **  ***

Dice 1:         3
Dice 2:         4

 *** **
     **

Dice 1:         1
Dice 2:         2

 *  **
```

Comment: What does *'Is there that the half of asterisk goes down?'* mean?

Comment: Is the issue the formatting of the output here? Because in both examples the correct number of asterisks are shown.

Comment: your output will for sure be bad if die value > 3, you print all the * in one line

Comment: You could create an array for each face. For example, a 5 would be `["* *", " * ", "* *"]`. Each string is one line of the face.

Comment: The approach will vary greatly based on what you're ALLOWED to do.  Are you supposed to build each row up and only output one row at a time, or are you allowed to "cheat" and MOVE the cursor around with `Console.SetCursorPosition()`?

Comment: I still don't understand what the _desired_ output should be for each value 1 to 6.

Comment: I believe each number should be displayed as THREE lines, with the first number on the LEFT and the second number on the RIGHT.  So you'd have to build up all of row 1 with the correct output for both numbers, then move on to row 2 and finally row 3.  See [this picture of dice](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/63/ca/a2/63caa2a915886143c80f25d23788e153.png) for a reference of what most dice sides look like.  *The expected output only shows two lines, so the author needs to explain more about how to correctly display each face, 1 thru 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of representing each face as three rows in a `String[][]`. The code generates 7 random rolls, stored them in a List, then outputs them:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class Program {

  public static Random rnd = new Random();
  public static List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
  
  public static String[][] sides = new String[][] {
    new String[] // 1
    {"   ", 
     " * ",
     "   "},

    new String[] // 2
    {"*  ",
     "   ",
     "  *"},

    new String[] // 3
    {"  *",
     " * ",
     "*  "},

    new String[] // 4
    {"* *",
     "   ",
     "* *"}, 

    new String[] // 5
    {"* *",
     " * ",
     "* *"}, 

    new String[] // 6
    {"* *",
     "* *",
     "* *"} 
  };
     
  public static void Main() {
    for(int i=0; i<7; i++) {
      numbers.Add(rnd.Next(1, 7));
    }
    Console.Write("Numbers: ");
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", numbers));

    for(int row=0; row<3; row++) {
      foreach(int number in numbers) {
        Console.Write(sides[number-1][row] + "   ");
      }
      Console.WriteLine();
    }
  }

}
```

Sample output:

```
Numbers: 1, 5, 1, 4, 6, 5, 4
      * *         * *   * *   * *   * *   
 *     *     *          * *    *          
      * *         * *   * *   * *   * *
```

Answer (score 3):

If this is the desired output

```
Dice1: 2
Dice2: 3

|*    |   |    *|
|     |   |  *  |
|    *|   |*    |
```

Then use the power of C# and define a `Dice` object which generates each dice with a random value and uses `ToString()` of text output.

**Dice.cs**

```
public class Dice
{
    static readonly Random rng = new Random();

    public Dice()
    {
        Roll();
    }

    public void Roll()
    {
        Value = rng.Next(1, 7);
    }
    public int Value { get; private set; }

    // Produce value number of asterisks 
    public override string ToString()
    {
        //  positions
        //
        // " [1]     [3] "
        // " [2] [0] [2] "
        // " [3]     [4] "

        // pos : values with *
        // [0] : 1, 3, 5
        // [1] : 2, 4, 5, 6
        // [2] : 6
        // [3] : 3, 4, 5, 6
        // [4] : 2, 4, 5, 6

        var bt = new System.Collections.BitArray(5);            
        // Bit array holds true/false for each of the
        // indicated positions above based on Value
        bt[0] = Value==1 || Value==3 || Value == 5;
        bt[1] = Value==2 || Value>=4;
        bt[2] = Value==6;
        bt[3] = Value >= 3;
        bt[4] = Value==2 || Value>=4;

        // Convert the bit array into an array of '*' or ' '
        var args = new object[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            args[i] = bt[i] ? '*' : ' ';
        }

        // Generate the multi-line representation of the dice
        // using the string formatting positions and values.
        return string.Format(
            "|{1}   {3}|" + Environment.NewLine
            +"|{2} {0} {2}|"+ Environment.NewLine
            +"|{3}   {4}|", args);

        // Example output:
        //|*   *|
        //|  *  |
        //|*   *|
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

Then in the main program, have a utility class `AppendColumns(width, item1, item2, ...)` that takes two or more *multiline* strings and appends them side by side based on the desired `width` for each one.

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var die1 = new Dice();
        var die2 = new Dice();

        Console.WriteLine($"Dice1: {die1.Value}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Dice2: {die2.Value}");
        Console.WriteLine(" ");

        Console.WriteLine(AppendColumns(9, die1, die2));
    }
    static string AppendColumns<T>(int width, params T[] items)
        // Convert objects into strings (possibly multiline)
        => AppendColumns(width, items.Select((i) => i.ToString()).ToArray());

    static string AppendColumns(int width, params string[] items)
    {
        // take multiple objects and convert into an array
        // of arrays, each with string[item][row]
        var parts = items.Select((item) => item.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)).ToArray();
        
        // Find the longest number of rows
        int rows = parts.Max((item) => item.Length);

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        // scan row by row
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            // scan item by item
            for (int index = 0; index < parts.Length; index++)
            {
                // if item has string in row: i use it
                var item = i<parts[index].Length ? parts[index][i] : string.Empty;
                // pad the string to the width
                sb.Append(item.PadRight(width));
                // add a space separator between items
                sb.Append(" ");
            }
            sb.AppendLine();
        }
        // return built-up string
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```